# Power Point VBA: Previous button click

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

Background: I have a power point presentation that will be used/modified/edited by many people without knowledge of VBA/ coding in general. There are shapes that I am trying to use at buttons to jump to sections in the power point. What I need is to record where they jump from with these buttons so I can get them back to the starting page. And they want to be able to move through a section, find a go back button and return from where they jumped. Multiplule buttons from other slides also jump to the same page/section.

All I need is to figure out what button they pressed without relying on these buttons specific names.

Basically is there an "active shape" command or something along those lines? or a way to get the name of a clicked button? And it needs to all happen in the presentation view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a public variable, assign it a value when clicking on the starting page button and retrieving that value with the sections last pages' back button.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're not trying to do this on a Mac (where it's broken)

```
Sub Example ( oSh as Shape )
  MsgBox oSh.Name & " says Stop POKING Me!!!"
End Sub
```

Assign the shape an Action Setting of Run Macro:  Example (or whatever you want to call it).